# I want to call 20 UIView files random and non-repeating in xcode

Tags: arc4random

I have a game where each click of the "next" button is supposed to call one of 20 subviews in at random order without repeating any of the UIViews. At count 20 the code should call a new UIView for scores.
Can someone pls. help.
LasloV in San Francisco

Comment: What do you have so far?  SO isn't really an implement it for me site - it's more of here's what I tried and having issue x.

Comment: //This is what I have, Unfortunately this is repeating: -(IBAction)random {
    int UIView = random() % 10;
    switch (UIView) {
        case 0:
            RandyViewController = [[randyViewController alloc]
                                   initWithNibName:@"randyViewController" bundle:nil];
            [self.view addSubview:View1];
            break;                       
 ....         default:
            break;
    }
}